# How to update items in listbox from new instances without flickering?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` bound to `ObservableCollection` with some items. They could be instances of base class or some inherited classes. I need to update item list once in 3 seconds. To update collection list item provider downloads new list and then I need to merge old and new lists. Items in old and new lists are associated using `Item.Id` property. The problem is how to update items in listbox without flickering and to preserve current selection etc.

There are two ways to do that

1. Do `list.RemoveAt()` and then `list.InsertAt()` to replace all items. Also it's useful to use `CollectionViewSource.DeferRefresh()` and save current selection before update and restore after. With this approach I encountered some issues like tooltip flickering etc.
2. The other way is to update each property of old items with new values. But this is kind of difficult because there are some inherited instances in the collection.

What is the proper way to handle such situation? How to efficiently implement live data updates (when updates are downloaded in new instance collection)?

Comment: I think i will work with some animation on the item. something like fade out -> removeAt -> insertAt -> fade in so you can't see flickering an the UX will be as smooth as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to limit the number of calls to PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged.

Update Property and check for new value == old and if so don't call NotifyPropertyChanged

If it is not a class match  then don't Remove Insert as that is two UI notifications.
Just assign the new item.  items[4] = newitem.

Are you using virtualizaton.
If the item is not displayed then I am pretty the UI does not get refresh.

Please see the below.  I am not getting any UI flickering other than the item or items updated.   I suspect you are not properly utilizing PropertyChanged.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewUpdate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add10000" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="UpdateFirst" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <Button Content="UpdateLast" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
            <Button Content="ReplaceFirst" Click="Button_Click_3" />
            <Button Content="UpdateAll" Click="Button_Click_4"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace ListViewUpdate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get { return persons; } }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (UInt16 i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                Persons.Add(new Person(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Persons.Count == 0) return;
            for (UInt16 i = 0; i < UInt16.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Persons[0].Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Persons.Count == 0) return;
            int last = Persons.Count - 1;
            for (UInt16 i = 0; i < UInt16.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Persons[last].Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Persons.Count == 0) return;
            for (UInt16 i = 0; i < UInt16.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Persons[0] = new Person(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Person p in Persons) p.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
    public class Person: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private string name;
        public string Name 
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name == value) return;
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public Person(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you implement it, it is always going to refresh the entire listbox. It is not the issue with different methods of listbox but how listbox paints the items in the list.

You might have to subclass the listbox and override its onpaint even and write in more efficient code to make it flickerfree.

I have done so in past on ListView
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3617/Flicker-free-ListView-in-NET-Part-2
Using this code.

May be this might help in developing a flicker free listbox also.

Comment: No an update to a single item does not cause a refresh of the entire listbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that I can use `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods just like this:

```
_listView.BeginUpdate();
_listView.Items.Clear();
_listView.Items.AddRange(newItems);
_listView.EndUpdate();
```

It didn't remove flicking at all, but it becomes much better, my eyes don't hurt.